# Adding template with data to layout file in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to add a template to my layout that has the same data on every page. For example, a list of recent posts in the sidebar of every page. What's the best way to go about doing something like that?

I've looked into partials and it seems like you feed data to it from the controller you're currently on. If I don't want to do that for every controller, do I just add a plug to the router pipeline that grabs the data and then feed it into a partial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a view and a template for what you want and add it to the layout view.

For example:

```elixir
# views/sidebar_view.ex

defmodule YourApp.SidebarView do
  use YourApp.Web, :view

  def recent_posts() do
    Post.get_recent_posts()
  end
end
```

```html
<!-- templates/layout/sidebar.html.eex -->

<ul>
  <%= for post <- recent_posts() do %>
    <li><%= post.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Then finally, in your layout:

```html
<!-- templates/layout/app.html.eex -->

<main role="main">
  <%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>
</main>

<aside role="complementary">
  <%= render YourApp.SidebarView, "sidebar.html" %>
</aside>
```